# fade on EACH element - on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to do to apply the fade, compared with their height, on `each` element and not the whole ?

**HTML :**

```
<div class="test fade"></div>
```

**CSS :**

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font: 1em 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.test {
    height: 70vh;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    margin: 1em auto;
}
```

**JS :**

```
var $elem = $('.test.fade');
for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    $elem.clone().appendTo('body');
}
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var percent = $(this).scrollTop() / ($(document).height() - $(this).height());
    $('.fade').each(function() {
        $(this).css('opacity', 1 - percent);
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9ejL3zoy/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using [`Element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to calculate the position of the element relative to the viewport.

With its position relative to the viewport, you can calculate how much % of it is outside the viewport and use that as `opacity` (after conversion to a 0-1 value):

```
var $elem = $('.test.fade');
for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    $elem.clone().appendTo('body');
}
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('.fade').each(function() {
    var bounds = this.getBoundingClientRect();
    var op = Math.max((bounds.height + Math.min(bounds.top, 0)) / bounds.height, 0);
    $(this).css('opacity', op);
  });
});
```

[**Demo JSFiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/8ye7rzbw/).